# GA4 - Automatically collected event parameters not being shown in firebase Debugview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to get the [GA4] Automatically collected events parameters in GA4 when receiving push notifications. But none of the parameters listed here (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en) showup in the event that GA receives.

As an example, in the debug view I can see notification_receive event coming in. As per the documentation above it should have the following parameters (message_name, message_time, message_device_time, message_id, topic, label, message_channel, message_type) automatically populated.

But looking at the event in the debug view i don't see any of the above parameters listed.
[image]

How can I see the automatically collected event in the debug view, is there any setting that I need to enable for this to work correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect Android device with a USB cabel to your PC. Then install adb a find app package name.

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <APP_PACKAGE_NAME>
```

After this command your events should be seen in almost real-time in debugView. Be aware that debugView is sometimes buggy, so check some tips below how to solve it.

If it still doesn't work try several times these "hacks" (refresh debugView, reconnect cable from PC and device, are you seeing a correct firebase project?).

Everything is well described in docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#android).